# Apache - Configuraion - Getting path inside relative Directory tag

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, git, dynamic

i have gitweb configuration for apache:

```
#/etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/\~([a-z]*\.[a-z]*)/gitweb/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.git)/?(\?.*)?$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi/$1 [L,PT]

<Directory /home/*/*/public_apache/gitweb>
  Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

My problem is that i can set just one project root for gitweb. So i want to set variable for gitweb configuration. Something like:

```
SetEnv  GITWEB_CONFIG_PROJECT_ROOT  /home/$1/$2/public_git
```

So i could use it in /etc/gitweb.conf. Something like:

`$projectroot = GITWEB_CONFIG_PROJECT_ROOT;`

So... My question is: **How can i get the path from *Direcotry* tag?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, do it with `mod_rewrite`, something like :

```
RewriteRule ^\~([a-z]*\.[a-z]*)/gitweb/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\.git/?(\?.*)?$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi/$1 [L,PT] [L,PT,E=GITWEB_CONFIG_PROJECT_ROOT:/home/$1/$2/public_git]
```

That is of course, if the user and the repository part are where I think they are in your `RewriteRule`. It may not work as I don't know all the details, but it may give you a hint of where to go from here.

Comment: For some reason the E= does not work for me. Strange is that SetEnv in directory tag works. 

Thank you. Ill try to discover this way